# Mongodb vs. Couch Db Select Performances

Tags: performance, select, mongodb, couchdb

I read many things about performance comparison between Couch Db and Mongo Db at insert capabilities. However at somewhere it says that Couch Db has a better read performance. Is there any performance comparison based on `select` capabilities of between that databases?

Comment: Why not set up some test cases and try it yourself? Then *you* could be the one to publish the comparisons.

Comment: @Crashworks I am searching about the performances but sure I will try to do some tests just started to try them. When I'm done why not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Don't trust benchmarks](http://till.klampaeckel.de/blog/archives/16-Measuring-CouchDB-performance.html)

[Good Benchmarks Are Non-Trivial](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/performance.html)

So [here](http://blog.fedecarg.com/2011/01/25/nosql-solutions-membase-redis-couchdb-and-mongodb/) you can see, that CouchDB has High Read performance and MongoDB has High Write performance. So you will have many read operations, use CouchDB.

Comment: Actually it statistics say that Mongo DB has much more better performance at writing. If Couch Db doesn't have a significant performance benefit I will prefer Mango. So I am trying to get some statistics about how much does it have a better performance from other. Thanks for your link I will examine it.

Comment: Just read what capabilities provides CouchDB and MongoDN and choose the one which you like more

Comment: I will use it for log searching. Reading is important for me but there will be a writing part too. So the comparisons show that Couch Db is not good at writing so I wanted to deep about their performances

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Sergey's links, make sure you also read http://jan.prima.de/plok/archives/175-Benchmarks-You-are-Doing-it-Wrong.html and http://jan.prima.de/plok/archives/176-Caveats-of-Evaluating-Databases.html

It is not that one is verbatim faster than the other. But either will pick a different set of trade-offs that will result in a certain performance for your use case. But that doesn't say they are doing the same and either is better or worse.